# Will this have a negative effect on the load time of my site?

Tags: jquery, performance

I am loading parts of my site (the header, footer and navigation) from separate HTML files like this

```
    $(function () {
        $("#navbar").load("nav.html");
        $("#header").load("header.html");
        $("#footer").load("footer.html");
    });
```

I am doing it this way to make editing certain elements for the entire website easier once I have developed more pages, the finished project will have around 20-30 pages.

The problem isn't the actual loading of them, they appear correctly as intended.

---

**My Question**:

Is it better for performance of the finished product to keep each of these elements inside every HTML file and then if i need to edit go back through each of them?

Comment: Off topic, but this could potentially be bad for SEO/crawlers, and also make your site unusable for anyone with JS disabled in their browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't expect this to have any significant performance impact.

The design impact, however, is huge. DRY – Don't Repeat Yourself. It's tiresome and error-prone.

It is very common to trade some performance for better readability and maintainability, because it's usually the right choice.

Not to be empty-worded, here is an excerpt by the amazing Jon Skeet (C# In Depth, fourth edition, p399)

> As a general principle, I wouldn’t start making any changes to your code to
>   improve performance before you’ve measured performance in a meaningful and
>   repeatable way and set goals for it. If you’re not careful, you can complicate your code
>   in the name of optimization, only to find out that even if you massively improved the
>   performance of one or two methods, those methods weren’t on a critical path for the
>   application anyway

If you do decide to do some bench marking, you might as well consider a non-js way.

`<object data="includes/header.html" type="text/html">  </object>`

If there is a performance difference I'd expect a pure-html approach to be quicker.

Answer (score 1):

with this approach you are getting the benefit of code reuse, and you load header, footer, nav files after you page loaded asynchronously actually but in this case you have 4 requests to server for loading your main file.
you load experience is faster because you load different parts partially and as I mentioned you modify only one place